# Help Troubleshooting 1st Greasemoney Script

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to do my first greasemoney script.  I'm fairly new to jquery and javascript, so be easy on me.

Here is what I have so far.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('a').each(function(i){
        if(this.href && this.innerHTML.indexOf('load more comments') > -1){
            toggle(this);
        }
    });
}, 4000);
```

The goal here is to click on all of the "load more comments" page on a sample reddit page like this, and to loop doing it every four seconds.

http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/i7hb5/why_assign_gender_to_public_bathrooms_if_there_is/

Right now, nothing happens at all.  I'm not sure how to troubleshoot. Is the script not being launched at all?  Is indexOf the right syntax for clicking the links?

Is there an online guide that would walk me though writing a basic greasemoney / jquery script like this?

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Edit:

Based on  Tomalak's response,

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           load all page comments
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// @namespace      none
// @include        http://www.reddit.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

setInterval( function () {
  $('a:contains(load more comments)').click();
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier than you think:

```
setInterval( function () {
  $('a:contains(load more comments)').click();
}, 4000);
```

Note that I use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

jQuery works in such a way that `click` is called on *every* matched element, i.e. there's no need for `each()` in this situation. Also see the [docs on the `:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Comment: That is so much cleaner, thanks.  So the links don't even need to be loaded into an array?

Comment: `$('a:contains(load more comments)')`*already returns* an array.

Comment: I updated the original post with the greasemonkey headers.  Do those look correct to you?  It's loading in jquery 1.3.2 because apparently there are issues with later versions.  Is there anything that needs to be done to trigger the script or will it run automatically?

Comment: Sorry, newbie question, but do selectors always return arrays then?  Because they are selecting a bunch of something?

Comment: @Brock, One last thing, does the 'load more comments' need to be in quotes at all because it's a string?  Or am I misunderstanding the syntax..

Comment: Use `$("a:contains('load more comments')")` the quotes are not always required but it's a good habit. ... [Link to jQuery ref for contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)  PS. note that the string is case-sensitive.

Comment: @some1: Yes, jQuery selectors *always* return an array. It might be of zero length or only contain one element, but it always will be an array.